# Calculus related rates snowball radius problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume

QUESTION: A sphere with radius $r$ has volume $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}r^3$ and surface area $4\pi r^2$.
A spherical snowball is melting in such a way that its volume is decreasing at a rate equal to twice the surface area. How quickly is the radius of the snowball decreasing?

So I did:

$V' = 2SA'$
or $4\pi r^2 = 16\pi r$ 
or $r = 4$.

This turned out to be wrong. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please avoid using words like "help" in the title. It is implicit that you are asking for help when you ask a question.

Comment: Read carefully the description and check whether you have used the correct formula.

Comment: You have to solve $V'=-2A.$ Indeed $V'(t)=-2A(t).$ Note that $r=r(t).$ And you are asked to get $r'(t).$

Comment: @mfl thank you very much.. but how exactly do i plug in the values for these terms? and what should i ultimately get as answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

We have that $$V'(t)=-2A(t).$$ In other words

$$4\pi r^2(t)r'(t)=-8\pi r^2(t).$$

Now, it should be easy to get $r'(t).$

Comment: so r'(t) = -2 ? does that seem correct?

Comment: In my opinion it is the correct answer.