# Calculus Related Rates Rectangle Area Problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Question: The length of a rectangle is increasing at a rate of $4$ inches per second while its width is decreasing at a rate of $3$ inches per second. At what rate, in square inches per second, is the area of the rectangle changing when its length is $23$ inches and its width is $18$ inches?

So I know for this problem that there is a third quantity that I can assign a variable to and solve an equation for. However, after giving this problem a great deal of thought, I can confidently say I am stuck. Where can I go from here?

Comment: You have asked a similar question a few minutes ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904206/calculus-related-rates-snowball-radius-problem. Have you learnt something with the answer to the previous question? Or you prefer to wait for an explicit answer?

Comment: $A=xy$, $\frac{dA}{dt}=y\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Comment: @mfl I prefer an explicit answer because these problems really are not the same

Comment: It is the same technique. Getting explicit answers don't improve your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the length and $y$ the width. Then:
$$E=xy$$
$$E'=x'y+xy'$$
We have from the given information that $x'=4$, $y'=-3$ (because it's decreasing), $x=23$ and $y=18$.

Can you continue?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, we now solve for when x=23 and y=18? what does that yield...?

Comment: Put those values on the above equation

Comment: Why is the down-vote?

Comment: i believe the answer is 3? does that make sense?

Comment: No it's 38!!!!!!

Comment: ?? how did you get your answer? I substituted the values into the E' equation?

Comment: Yes you are correct! Sorry! I forgot to have a coffee and now I am falling asleep!! :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82683/discussion-between-mathperson1234-and-anastassis-kapetanakis).

Comment: does that answer make sense though? that the area of the rectangle is changing at a rate of 3 inches per second squared?

Comment: Yes! What's wrong about it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$=length, $y$=width.

$$A=xy$$

You know $\frac{dx}{dt}=4 
\;\frac{\text{inches}}{\text{sec}}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=-3 \; \frac{\text{inches}}{\text{sec}}$.

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}$$

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=23\cdot {-3}+18\cdot{4}$$

$$\frac{dA}{dt}= 3 \frac{\text{inches}^2}{\text{sec}}$$

Comment: Yes that is what i need to calculate. what else can i do?

Comment: Explain the downvotes please?